# How to install Ubuntu in Asus Eee PC 1015CX?

Tags: 12.04

Hi I would love to use ubuntu as my default OS in my new Asus Eee PC 1015CX. It comes with a default Express Gate cloud OS and I would like to know the steps on how to create a USB bootable drive and install. Can somebody, please,help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: The unit came also with Windows 7 starter. Right?

Answer (score 0):

To run Ubuntu from a USB stick, the first thing you need to do is to insert a USB stick with at least 2GB of free space into your PC.

1. [Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. [How to run Ubuntu from a DVD or USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Ubuntu Desktop OS from here - www​. ubuntu .com/ download/desktop
2. Burn it to a pendrive using softwares like rufus. Get it from here - rufus.akeo.ie
3. Now, connect your pendrive to your Eee Pc.
4. Go to the BIOS menu of your PC using keys like - f1, f2, f12, del, esc, etc. Every PC has different keys, so, see to that.
5. And then go to the option BOOT - there set your pendrive as your first priority / choose pendrive (if it is a boot selection menu).

Then just install your ubuntu. :)

For any further info as to how to install ubuntu or if you arr facing any problem, please add your comments below. :)